# Regular Expression in Pentaho TextFileInput step

Tags: pentaho

I am trying to read some csv files from a folder via pentaho textfileinput step. I need to use a regex to read files with filename containing a string in it. Can someone help me to do it?

My files are named
 
10/11/1992_file1_userdata.txt 
11/11/1992_file2_userdata.txt

So userdata is the common string. I tried .userdata.backslash.txt in the regex box, but it is not picking any files.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your file and expected output? Can you show us what you tried, what didn't work and why it didn't work?

Comment: The "Regular Expression" box on the `Text file input` properties page can accept Java regular expressions.

Comment: @HenrikIlgen I have added the file format, can u please see it

Answer (score 0):

Please, can you try this *_userdata.*txt in RegExp Field